# uniform matrix not being assigned to shader

Tags: c#, opentk

im trying to apply a rotation matrix to my shader and when i try to set it and mult it in the shader my triangle doesn't render

my drawing code:

```
        var rotmat = Matrix4d.CreateRotationZ(45);

        shader.SetMatrix("transform", rotmat);

        shader.Use();
        mesh.Draw();
```

shader.SetMatrix:

```
    public void SetMatrix(string name,Matrix4d mat)
    {
        int index = GL.GetUniformLocation(Program, name);
        GL.UniformMatrix4(index, false,ref mat);
    }
```

vertex shader code:

```
#version 440 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 color;
layout(location = 20)uniform mat4 transform;

out vec4 fragcolor;

void main(void)
{
  gl_Position = transform * vec4(position,1.0);
  fragcolor = color;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because in OpenGL uniform values (set by glUniform calls) are part of program object state, i.e. specific to the currently bound program.

If you wish to change a uniform value you must bind the program first (via `glUseProgram`); in your code that means calling shader.Use *before* shader.SetMatrix.

Depending on your GL version you may alternately be able to call `glProgramUniformMatrix4fv` which doesn't require the program to be bound first.

Comment: it's still not showing my triangle, do i have to use a projection and view matrix too?

Comment: it works when i use a float based matrix but it won't work with a double based matrix do you know any way to fix this? im making a minecraft like game and im trying to use double precision

Comment: @vincentcastro I think you want `dmat4` instead of `mat4`. Similarly, there are `dvec3` and `dvec4`. See [Data Type (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)).

Comment: ... But make sure your GPU supports doubles first. And remember, Minecraft itself doesn't use doubles, so there is always another way. In fact, this would be better as a separate question rather than an ongoing discussion in comments.